# Put JSON data into HTML elements

Tags: html, json

I want to put values from a JSON object into HTML elements.
If I break this down into steps, I think I know the first two steps, but then I am lost

1. get the html elements into javascript objects using a loop and selectors
2. get the values of the JSON properties one by one using a for...in loop
3. ...

I am already at a stumbling block in step 1, as I don't know how to select by ID when iterating over the set of elements.

I would like help to understand the steps I need to define for this task, as well as any advice about which functions to use.

This is the JSON :

```
var sonnet_1 = { 
    line_1 : "FROM fairest creatures we desire increase", 
    line_2 : "That thereby beauty\'s rose might never die", 
    line_3 : "But as the riper should by time decease,",    
    line_4 : "His tender heir might bear his memory\:", }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<p id = "1"></p>
<p id = "2"></p>
<p id = "3"></p>
<p id = "4"></p>
```

Step 1 ) I have tried this

First, tested a single query

```
document.getElementById('1');
```

OK. output: `<p id ="1"></p>`

```
for (i= 0; i< 14 ; i++) {
        var line = document.getELementById('i');
        console.log(line);
    }
```

I am expecting output:

```
<p id ="1"></p>
<p id ="2"></p>
...
```

But instead this doesn't log anything.

Step 2)

Tried this :

```
console.log(`${sonnet_1[line]}`);
```

Output: FROM fairest creatures we desire increase

All good!

Then this:

```
for (line in sonnet_1) {    
        console.log(`${sonnet_1[line]}`);
    }
```

Again all good.

Output:
FROM fairest creatures we desire increase
That thereby beauty's rose might never die
But as the riper should by time decease,
His tender heir might bear his memory:

Then this:

```
for (line in sonnet_1) {    
        document.getElementById(`${line}`).innerHTML = `${sonnet_1[line]}`;
    }
```

No luck.

I think I need an embedded loop. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Before going to js put a div with id, lets `id="div"`;

```
let x;
for (i in sonnet_1) {
  x += '<p>' + sonnet_1[i] + '</p>';
}
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right direction.

```
let i = 1;
for (line in sonnet_1) {
    // console.log(i++, sonnet_1[line]);
    document.getElementById(`${i++}`).innerHTML = `${sonnet_1[line]}`;
}
```

If you want to create dynamic list of 'p' elements over the JSON object, try this:

```
let i = 1;
let htmlStr = '';
for (line in sonnet_1) {
    htmlStr = htmlStr + `<p id='${i}'>${sonnet_1[line]}</p>`
}

console.log(htmlStr);
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/i4irsh/pen/GRjgpEV)